# how to define one condition that validate at least one key in iam aws policy

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, policy

I check a solution to define a policy that accept only one of both IP addresses as source IP "OR" a source VPC (pool of private IP addresses) - PSB

By definition, there is an "AND" between the keys in same condition
(https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_multi-value-conditions.html)

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Action": "*",
            "Resource": "*",
            "Condition": {
                "NotIpAddress": {
                    "aws:SourceIp": [
                        "11.11.11.11/32",
                        "22.22.22.22/32"
                    ]
                },
                "Bool": {
                    "aws:ViaAWSService": "false"
                },
                "StringNotEquals": {
                    "aws:SourceVpc": [
                        "vpc-00222222222222"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ] 
}
```

thanks

Answer (score 1):

You have to **duplicate your statements** for OR. I know that's code duplication and its not "pretty", but this is how it is done (I'm not sure what you want to do with your `Bool`):

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Action": "*",
            "Resource": "*",
            "Condition": {
                "NotIpAddress": {
                    "aws:SourceIp": [
                        "11.11.11.11/32",
                        "22.22.22.22/32"
                    ]
                },
                "Bool": {
                    "aws:ViaAWSService": "false"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Action": "*",
            "Resource": "*",
            "Condition": {
               "Bool": {
                    "aws:ViaAWSService": "false"
                },
                "StringNotEquals": {
                    "aws:SourceVpc": [
                        "vpc-00222222222222"
                    ]
                }
            }
        },

    ] 
}
```

Comment: I thought that there is an "AND" between 2 conditions as mentioned in the link above?

Comment: @MauriceAmar Yes, so to get OR, you have to make two statements.

Comment: @MauriceAmar How did it go. Is it still unclear how to get OR?